# combining the name of the file with todays date

Tags: java, file

I am creating an excel sheet in c: with this name ABC_0607 and it also get created as shown below..

```
String outputDir = "C:/Report/";
FileOutputStream fw = new FileOutputStream(new File(outputDir, "ABC_0607.xls"));
```

Now as I am recieving this files on a daily basis and need to be stored in c: drive 
so  I want to modify it name a little bit that is combination of filename+MM/DD/YYYY
so if today date is 3-July-2013 so file name should be like ABC_0607-MM/DD/YYYY that is ABC_0607-07/03/2013.

PLease advise how to achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this method to retrieve the name of your file:

```
public String getFileNameFrom(String name) {
    String currDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd").format(new Date());
    return name + "-" + currDate;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `StringBuilder` initialized with the name of the file.Format the `Date` using a `DateFormat` and append the `String` to it.  Put the entire logic inside a method so that it can be reused without code duplication.

Comment: @TuntundresFewfew No. Please check here: [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) and [DateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html).

And start writing your own code. 

PS: I'm going to downvote anybody who's giving code on this question. Sorry!

Comment: Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println("Now: "+formatter.format(now.getTime()) );

Comment: @DavidHofmann Yeah, David. I saw that... both happened rather simultaneously. That's why I didn't downvote you. :)

However, let's note this for the future.

Answer (score 0):

I have following code to create name for log file, it can be hourly, daily or minutely(lol)

```
SimpleDateFormat ymd = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd");
SimpleDateFormat ymdh = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_HH");
SimpleDateFormat ymdhm = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm");

Calendar dt = Calendar.getInstance();
dt.setTimeInMillis(moment);
String fName;
if (_splitType == SPLIT_HOUR)
    fName = ymdh.format(dt.getTime());
else if (_splitType == SPLIT_MINUTE)
    fName = ymdhm.format(dt.getTime());
else
    fName = ymd.format(dt.getTime());
```